# While reading excel sheet in data table some row order no comes empty

Tags: c#, vb.net

am reading excel sheet with the below connetion,but in one order no some rows comes empty row, but excel sheet the row has present..

```
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";
ExtendedProperties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0';"
```

How can I read all in the Order NI from the Excel Sheet?

Comment: If the Excel sheet has merged cells, you can try `IMEX=1`

Comment: You'd better show your code and excel data. Now it is blind guess. We need to know detail to help you

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest